# Global variable in all templates Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I was authorized under user and object `Auth::user()` is not empty. So using this object and relations between models therefore I can get status of user from `Users` table:

```
$profileStatus = Auth::user()->user->first()->status;
```

How to share this variable `$profileStatus` in all template in Laravel to show/hide HTML blocks depend this value (active/not active)?

Comment: Maybe better to add `status` directly to `Auth:user()->status`? is it possible?

Comment: Isn't Auth::user() already a User model?  What's the point of Auth::user()->user->first() here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once User successfully logged in, you can set status in globally like

> View::share('user_status', $profileStatus);

then you can access user_status from your entire application including blade templates.

Comment: View::share is normally used in service providers, so I wouldn't recommend share here, since the auth session may not be available when a service provider is booted.